# Moderator site analytics chart is buggy

Tags: bug, status-completed, analytics

With the analytics chart when I try to hover over a particular point it shows nothing or flickers for a split second on Firefox, on IE it shows an x and y value (date to count) which is something new so I guess there has been an update. Even in IE the dialog box mostly flashes.

The x / y think is definitely new so something must have changed in the last 24 hours, but it is now unreadable.

I personally feel the date adds nothing of value, if anything I would prefer to see the name of the day of the week than the date.

https://chinese.stackexchange.com/admin/analytics

[image]

Comment: This is a little unclear; what would help is a link to what you're looking at. That way, we can validate and review the potential bug.

Comment: @Emrakul - See updated details

Answer (score 5):

Hover should be fixed in the next build, and we'll be showing both the date and the day of the week in the tooltip.

Comment: Anna, I noticed there appears to be another change since I took that screenshot this morning. The options "show raw data" and "show moving average" are now radio buttons instead of check buttons and you can't select both.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Yeah, that's by design. If you frequently use both graphs at the same time, let me know what you get out of doing that.

Comment: @Anna I do rather like seeing both at the same time, as you get more information - you get the specific details, while still having a nice level line for your mind to comprehend.

Comment: @AnnaLear - It wasn't like that up until yesterday. I second reinstating how it was. I want to know both lots of information. I want to know how we at tracking and how many people arrived each day and I don't want to make an unnecessary extra click to do it. I always have both turned on (refer to image above).

Comment: @AnnaLear - The chart is still doing the flickering thing this morning, although I think it stopped at some point on the weekend. I also remembered why I like to see both the daily traffic and the trend at the same time, so I can see which days have exceeded the trend.

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 The checkboxes should be back now. :)

Comment: Ahhh, almost... now there's a new issue, the number of checkboxes has doubled